# Slicing tensor with list - TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to accomplish this method of slicing in Tensorflow (example shown using numpy)?

```
z = np.random.random((3,7,7,12))
x = z[...,[0,5]]
```

such that

```
x_hat = np.concatenate([z[...,[0]], z[...,[5]]], 3)
assert np.all(x == x_hat)
x.shape # (3, 7, 7, 2)
```

in Tensorflow, this operation

```
tfz = tf.constant(z)
i = np.array([0,5] dtype=np.int32)
tfx = tfz[...,i]
```

throws the error

```
ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 1
From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for 'strided_slice/stack_1' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [], [2].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a shape error like greeness said. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a simple way of doing it like I hoped, but this is the generalized solution I came up with:

```
def list_slice(tensor, indices, axis):
    """
    Args
    ----
    tensor (Tensor) : input tensor to slice
    indices ( [int] ) : list of indices of where to perform slices
    axis (int) : the axis to perform the slice on
    """

    slices = []   

    ## Set the shape of the output tensor. 
    # Set any unknown dimensions to -1, so that reshape can infer it correctly. 
    # Set the dimension in the slice direction to be 1, so that overall dimensions are preserved during the operation
    shape = tensor.get_shape().as_list()
    shape[shape==None] = -1
    shape[axis] = 1

    nd = len(shape)

    for i in indices:   
        _slice = [slice(None)]*nd
        _slice[axis] = slice(i,i+1)
        slices.append(tf.reshape(tensor[_slice], shape))

    return tf.concat(slices, axis=axis)



z = np.random.random(size=(3, 7, 7, 12))
x = z[...,[0,5]]
tfz = tf.constant(z)
tfx_hat = list_slice(tfz, [0, 5], axis=3)
x_hat = tfx_hat.eval()

assert np.all(x == x_hat)
```

Comment: I like your generalization.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
x = tf.stack([tfz[..., i] for i in [0,5]], axis=-1)
```

This works for me:

```
z = np.random.random((3,7,7,12))
tfz = tf.constant(z)
x = tf.stack([tfz[..., i] for i in [0,5]], axis=-1)

x_hat = np.concatenate([z[...,[0]], z[...,[5]]], 3)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    x_run = sess.run(x)

assert np.all(x_run == x_hat)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a reshape to make the result of concatenation consistent with the original shape (the first 3 dimensions).

```
z = np.arange(36)
tfz = tf.reshape(tf.constant(z), [2, 3, 2, 3])
slice1 = tf.reshape(tfz[:,:,:,1], [2, 3, -1, 1])
slice2 = tf.reshape(tfz[:,:,:,2], [2, 3, -1, 1])
slice = tf.concat([slice1, slice2], axis=3)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print sess.run([tfz, slice])


> [[[[ 0,  1,  2],
     [ 3,  4,  5]],

    [[ 6,  7,  8],
     [ 9, 10, 11]],

    [[12, 13, 14],
     [15, 16, 17]]],

   [[[18, 19, 20],
     [21, 22, 23]],

    [[24, 25, 26],
     [27, 28, 29]],

    [[30, 31, 32],
     [33, 34, 35]]]]

  # Get the last two columns
> [[[[ 1,  2],
     [ 4,  5]],

    [[ 7,  8],
     [10, 11]],

    [[13, 14],
     [16, 17]]],

   [[[19, 20],
     [22, 23]],

    [[25, 26],
     [28, 29]],

    [[31, 32],
     [34, 35]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

[tf.gather()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) performs exactly what you want, if I understand well what you're willing to accomplish.

```
tf.gather(
    params, indices, validate_indices=None, axis=None, batch_dims=0, name=None
)
```

> Gather slices from params axis axis according to indices. indices must
> be an integer tensor of any dimension (often 1-D).